# A verb or verbal phrase to describe a start of a long successful period in sports

Tags: выражения

How to describe a successful action of a player in a national team that would start a relatively long period of success for that team?

For example,

> И тут он забил гол, тем самым **начав подъём** российского футбола.

"Начав подьём" doesn't sit right with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your example my suggestion is

> И тут он забил гол, тем самым **дав толчок/старт** подъёму российского футбола.

or you can express the idea in a roundabout way

> И тут он забил гол, **ставший/который стал началом** возрождения
>   российского футбола
>
> И тут он забил гол, **после которого/вслед за которым** началось
>   возрождение российского футбола

But for the situation you've described, which is different from the one represented by the actual example, **положить начало** fits perfectly

> Забитый им финальный гол положил начало серии побед команды на
>   чемпионате.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, everything is fine. As far as style, I believe `положить начало чему-либо` is better:

> И тут он забил гол, тем самым **положив начало подъёму** российского футбола.

It will have the meaning of the scorer laying the symbolic foundation for the rise of Russian football.

Comment: Can you, please, try to come up with something more dynamic than "laying the foundation"?  I need something more like a "kickstart".

Comment: @brilliant How about "запустив подъём"? From "запускать" meaning to launch.

Comment: "запустив" sounds great! But does it go along well with "подъём"?

Comment: @brilliant *запускают* usually *процесс*, but the construction *запустить процесс подъёма* sounds very clunky and simply unidiomatic

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка you can easily find "запустили подъём курса рубля" or "запустили подъём российского производства" or "запустили подъём экономики"

Comment: while i agree that your examples aren't totally unthinkable [*запустили подъём курса рубля*](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&source=hp&ei=H-UEXNT1H4SZsgGH45bYBw&q="запустили+подъём+курса+рубля") is not found in Google as well as *запустил* and *запустить*, [*запустили подъём российского производства*](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=wOUEXN3jGMa8swG8lojwBA&q="запустили+подъём+российского+производства") occurs only 6 times in Google, *запустил* and *запустить* don't occur at all

Comment: likewise is not found *запустил(и) подъём экономики*, there're as many as 28 occurrences of [*запустить подъём экономики*](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=huYEXJuzJ8KWsAH_ibuABg&q="запустить+подъём+экономики").... so i wouldn't say that such phrases are particularly *easy* to find

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка there's also "запустить подъём доллара", "запустить подъём рынка", "запустить подъём уровня гормонов", and even "запустить подъём ура-патриотических настроений", lol. They aren't as numerous as I initially thought though, I agree... 

Biggest problem with OP's scenario, in my opinion, is that he's overly dramatic -- one goal can't start the rise so it would sound weird in any language. But something like "реформы министра спорта привели к реорганизации, начав подъём российского футбола" could work, no?

Comment: yes, if we speak of football i could imagine one victory being a start of some prolonged process but not a single goal even if it sealed such victory

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Even a victory wouldn't make much sense to me. It could be a symbolic milestone, which signaled and retrospectively predicted the rise, but you can't really attribute it to a single 90-minute event, and "начав подъём" has that feeling of attribution, like the victory itself was what started it. Could sound like I'm splitting hairs here, just want to make sure OP understands that this "начав подъём" sounds like this goal or even this victory is what explains the start of the rise, which in reality would most likely be nonsense.

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка: What's so overly dramatic about it? It's absolutely ok to say that someone's single scoring has kickstarted the national rise in some sport: "Paul Caligiuri scored a golazo on Trinidadian soil to kickstart American soccer’s rise" (https://sports.yahoo.com/u-s-loses-trinidad-fails-qualify-2018-world-cup-015400543.html)

Comment: @brilliant conceptually this idea is foreign to me, i fail to imagine a single goal starting certain phenomenon, i could imagine it being a starting point thereof, but not the actual impetus, not sure how much such point of view is conditioned by my mother tongue

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка - To think that a single goal in "that goal kickstarted the rise..." is an actual impetus is like thinking of a physical act of touching  in "we don't wont to touch that topic"

Comment: @brilliant if understand correctly you mean it figuratively, but still logically even as a figure of speech it doesn't sound idiomatic to me, logically and idiomatically i'd word it **гол стал началом/отправной точкой подъёма/возрождения**, which doesn't mean it was the actual trigger

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка The phrase "that goal kickstarted the rise..." sounds quite idiomatic to me, especially in the sports context. And, of course, it's understood that the "goal" in that phrase is not the actual trigger. It's like "don't let it bring you down" doesn't imply that something is going to take you and bring you somewhere else.

Comment: @brilliant by being idiomatic i mean in Russian, i can't speak for English, i guess we'll have to just agree to disagree and leave it at that

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка - So we were talking about two different languages. I was speaking about English, not Russian. BTW, is there any word in Russian that would encompass both the "trigger" and "the starting point" meanings? How about the word "старт" that you've used in your answer? What if I say "это стало стартом для возрождения...", will it be understood as a trigger or as a starting point, or as both?

Comment: @brilliant due to the presence of the preposition *для* i believe it will have a tendency to be understood as a trigger, like it wasn't a part of the process but an external factor which gave it a start, but dispensing with *для* will make the sentence awkward, старт is a tricky word, so i would opt for the simple *стало началом возрождения*

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка - What about "это стало стартом в возрождении... "? Besides, does the "стало началом возрождения" not exclude the "trigger" meaning?

Comment: @brilliant _стало стартом в возрождении_ while technically correct sounds wrong to me. There's a phrase _стать стартом во что-то_, e.g. _стало стартом в новую жизнь_ and _стало стартом в прекрасное будущее_. Perhaps, _стало стартом в возрождение футбола_ is not too bad. Also, you could reconsider using the word _подъём_ if it doesn't mix with _запустить_ and say _запустило возрождение российского футбола_. This, imo, will both sound right and have both meanings. [link](https://www.google.ru/search?q="запустить+возрождение") and [link](https://www.google.ru/search?q="запустил+возрождение")

Comment: @brilliant Personally, I still wouldn't say that _гол запустил возрождение футбола_, because, as I've said, it sounds overly dramatic to me, and the parallels with the kickstart phrases in English don't help as, as already explored by БаянКупи-ка, they sound idiomatic in English and there's no literal equivalent for them in Russian, but perhaps it's just a matter of taste and _гол запустил возрождение футбола_ will convey exactly what you want it to.

Comment: @brilliant *стало стартом* doesn't sound nice both phraseology and euphony wise, i guess i'll have to fall back on the suggestions i gave in my formal answer, *стало началом* indeed excludes the trigger aspect

Comment: i have to mention that *стало стартом в + Accusative* is poor Russian, there's a stable collocation *стать/быть путёвкой в...*, and although Google search returns slightly more results than it does to earlier suggestions, their score is still relatively low, it seems the majority come from some backwater websites and pages whose authors aren't necessarily gifted writers and credible in terms of language finess

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86571/discussion-on-answer-by-user75619-a-verb-or-verbal-phrase-to-describe-a-start-of).

Comment: Here is my final choice: "забил гол, что стало своего рода стартом в возрождении российского футбола"

Comment: The words положить and подъем have different directions. The phrase положить начало подъему sounds far-fetched.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, a conclusion about the long-term meaning of such a fact comes to minds *after a while*. For that reason, the idea that somebody started a new epoch by kicking a ball doesn't sound too natural. I'd try to change the sentence like this:

> И тут он забил гол, с которым позже *стали связывать начало подъёма* в
>   развитии российского футбола.

Comment: "стали связывать начало подъём" - Why would somebody need to start tying up the beginning???

Comment: @brilliant Not literally. Linking one with the other, connecting, associating, attributing etc.

Answer (score 0):

> ..., и этим **начал череду успешных выступлений** команды...
>
> ..., **с которого начался взлёт** {отечественного футбола}.
>
> (успешное выступление команды) **ознаменовало новую волну возрождения**
>   российского футбола
>
> (успехи сборной на чемпионате) **вдохновили** команду **на новые
>   победы**/российских футболистов **на новые достижения**
>
> забил гол, **ставший первой ласточкой новой весны** российского футбола ("первая ласточка" is an idiom)

And miscellaneous. 
I am under the impression that the larger half of expressions to describe this phenomenon are not idioms and can be translated from your first language. Think of a proper metaphor.